# sqlsrv UPDATE statement runs but doesn't update DB

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have an issue where my PHP sqlsrv UPDATE statement runs and doesn't return any errors but nothing in the DB ever changes and the row is not actually updated. Is there something I am missing that would allow this query to appear to run successfully but not update the row?

I have checked that the update statement runs in SQL server management studio and it updates the row.

```
$visitquery = "UPDATE tblVisit SET CalledInBy='WINNER' WHERE VisitID='3679061'";            

                    $visitClose = sqlsrv_prepare($connect,$visitquery);
                    if( sqlsrv_execute( $visitClose))
                        {
                              echo "Statement executed.\n <br />";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             echo "Error in executing statement.\n";
                             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        }
```

Comment: Could it be there are no matching rows for your where clause? Try `sqlsrv_rows_affected($visitClose)`  after calling `sqlsrv_execute` to see how many rows were affected by the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Do you ***know*** that you have a record where `VisitID` = `'3679061'`?  *(No typos, no mis-matched data types?)*

Comment: Also, add the db and schema names to the objects in your statement, like MAIN.dbo.tblvisit or some such.

Comment: @JonathanAmend 1 row affected but still no update in the DB

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, looking at it now in SSMS, just double checked.

Comment: @EricHauenstein DB & Schema added still no record updated.

Comment: Any chance you called `sqlsrv_begin_transaction` somewhere and forgot to call `sqlsrv_commit`?

Comment: As far as I can see the code is calling sqlsrv_begin_transaction but I cant see sqlsrv_commit anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @JonathanAmend

`sqlsrv_begin_transaction` was opened but wasn't calling `sqlsrv_commit`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-commit.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your script has permission to access the correct database or nothing will happen to the tables.

So first, establish a connection to the database then specify the database that contains your table.

In your setup, add this line above your code.

```
$connect = sqlsrv_connect(server format goes here,array("Database"=>name of database containing tblVisit in quotes goes here,"UID"=>username to access database goes here,"PWD"=>password to access database goes here));
```

For each value, enclose them with quotes since they are strings.

There is more information on how to make the code here:

[See this (at php.net)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)