# Sending date query to database

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
    $date = getdate();
    $query = "UPDATE Members Set Name = '$desiredName', Latest_Update = '$date'  Where ID = '$currentID'";
    if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "Record successfully updated.";
    }
```

I have this query to update a name of a member and whenever I update the name I want to also update the time of the update. Currently this query does not work with the Latest_Update query but everything else works if I remove that. My question is how do I update a datetimeoffset using this query? As at the moment, it does not send the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [`SQL Server equivalent of MySQL's NOW()?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385042/sql-server-equivalent-of-mysqls-now) - `$query = "UPDATE Members Set Name = '$desiredName', Latest_Update = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()  Where ID = '$currentID'";`? [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740480/sqlsrv-update-statement-runs-but-doesnt-update-db
Try the above link Possible you can find your answer.

Comment: @Sean Put that as an answer, it worked. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create the datetime in php, use the built in function `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`

```
$query = "UPDATE Members Set Name = '$desiredName', Latest_Update = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() Where ID = '$currentID'";
```